# need to click twice on a button

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have programmed a simple game where I used a bootstrap button to start a new game or do another game.

The first click (to start a new game) works well. Then when I want to do another game (by stopping and reinitializing the current game), it works also.

My problem is located in the reinitialization of this latter game (so, the second restart): I have to click the bootstrap button twice.

Here is the Javascript code snippet (the bootstrap button is `buttonNewGame`):

```
var buttonNewGame = document.getElementById('buttonNewGame');

function startGame() {
  // If currentGame then call initGame
  if (isCurrentGame) {
    isCurrentGame = false;
    initGame();
    console.log('HERE : stop and reinitialize current game');
  } 
  else {
    isCurrentGame = true;
  }

  // Call main function
  currentGame();
}
```

For the situation where I need to click twice, the `console.log('HERE : stop and reinitialize current game');` shows nothing for the first click, then it calls `startGame()` at the second click.

Is this related to a problem of focus or a problem with the bootstrap button?

Thanks

Comment: So just check than isCurrentGame has value expected. I guess you don't reinitialize it when needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the order of execution, you will notice that the first time you go into the `startGame()` the value for the `isCurrentGame` is `false` which is why it does not print the `console.log`.

The first time it goes in the `startGame()`, the value of `isCurrentGame` is changed to true, which is why, when you go in the second time. It goes inside the if condition.

To solve this, you would need to reset the value of `isCurrentGame` to true when the button is invoked

First time:

The value of `isCurrentGame` is `false`, so it will go in the else and will be assigned true.

```
if (isCurrentGame) {
    isCurrentGame = false;
    initGame();
    console.log('HERE : stop and reinitialize current game');
} else
    isCurrentGame = true;
```

the second time it goes in, the `isCurrentGame` is `true`, so it'll go inside the if condition and invoke the `initGame()` and will print `console.log`